# Count JSON values

Tags: json

```
request(getuser, function(err, res, body) {
    let user = JSON.parse(body);
    let amount = // Show amount of groups
})
```

Basically `user` Has this part in the json:

```
"groups":[  
    {  
        "id":"001",
        "name":"Group 1",
    },
    {  
        "id":"002",
        "name":"Group 2",
    }
],
```

This is only a small part, my question is how can I count how many "groups" there are? I could not find any similar questions to this on the internet, I would appreciate any code example.

Comment: You want the count in which language?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow guide on how to ask a questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the number of elements inside the groups array, you can use the length function.

amount = user.groups.length;